# increment button is not working in magento

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, magento, magento-1.8

I am using magento 1.8.1. I am using magento 1.8.1 and i changed the increment decrements scripts. with the change of there design.

```js
jQuery(function() {

    jQuery("div.add-to-cart .qty_pan").append('<div class="inc add">&#8250;</div><div class="dec add">&#8249;</div>');

    jQuery("#plus, #minus").click(function(){
      
        var jQueryadd = jQuery(this);
        var oldValue = jQueryadd.parent().find("input").val();
  var newVal = 0;
    
        if (jQueryadd.text() == "+") {
        newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
       // AJAX save would go here
     } else {
       // Don't allow decrementing below zero
       if (oldValue > 1) {
           newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
           // AJAX save would go here
       }
    if(oldValue == 1){
     newVal = parseFloat(oldValue);
     }
     }
     jQueryadd.parent().find("input").val(newVal);
    });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <button id="plus" class="btnplus">+</button>
  <div class="qty_pan">
    <input type="text" min="1" max="1000" name="qty" id="qty" value="1" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
  </div>
  <button id="minus" class="btnminus">-</button>
```

now the problem is, when i click on plus button or minus button, the quantity change but it go direct to cart page. i don't know how to cart page link with that. so please help me.

[see here on my website](http://54.169.14.119/index.php/purple-turtle-baby-wet-wipes-with-lid-80pc.html)

Comment: You load twice jQuery, the 1.4.4 (very old) and 2.1.1. You should take care here, that will bring you problems.

Comment: so, can i delete the older version jquery?

Comment: If you do so, you will maybe face to trouble. It's up to you to see.

Comment: ok. so please tell me how to update new version?

Comment: I'm not using magento, so consider reading the documentation to update it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since default button type is submit, it will submit the form.You need to use `event.preventDefault()` inside click handling function.

```
jQuery("#plus, #minus").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault()
```

Comment: i did this, but same result, still it is redirected to cart page

Comment: or can you make changes in coading, so i can conform with my changes.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever plan to use extra **button element** except primary submit button in form, best practices says

> **Always specify the type attribute for  `<button>` element**.

Example : Generally use `type="button"`

```
<button type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

So it will not break submit follow.